# How to automatically release mouse button when another button is pressed

Tags: lua, macros, mouse, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Is it possible to program a lua script that every time I press RMB + LMB (in that order), RMB releases when LMB is pressed? The idea is: Clicking LMB will 'cancel' RMB, **but RMB will be retaken (since I keep pressing it) when LMB was released**. I play a game that I need to smash (not both at the same time) RMB (aim) and then LMB (spell) multiple times (and fast) to send multiple spells in a faster way, **but every time I throw the spell (LMB), I need to aim again (RMB)** to send another. The concept is that I want to just keep RMB (aim) pressed and smash LMB (spell) only, and with this script the game will understand I'm actually aiming again after every spell, while I'm just pressing the aim button.

If possible, it would be cool to turn this on/off on RCTRL key.
Thank you!

Comment: RCTRL cannot work as a toggle key in LGS/GHUB.  But it is possible to make script work while you keep RCTRL down.  Or any other mouse button can be used as a toggle key.

Comment: Oh, true history my dude.
So it can be Mouse3!

Answer (score 0):

**Step #1**

Set the script

```
local spell_while_aim, active, rmb_is_down

local function RMB()
   rmb_is_down = not rmb_is_down
   if rmb_is_down then
      PressMouseButton(3)
   else
      ReleaseMouseButton(3)
   end
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then  -- left
      if active and rmb_is_down then
         RMB()
         spell_while_aim = true
      end
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1 then -- left
      if spell_while_aim then
         spell_while_aim = false
         Sleep(20)
         RMB()
      end
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2 then  -- right
      RMB()
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 2 then -- right
      if spell_while_aim then
         spell_while_aim = false
      else
         RMB()
      end
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 3 then  -- middle
      active = not active
   elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
      ReleaseMouseButton(3)
   end
end
```

**Step #2**

Unassign standard command "Right Click" from physical mouse button #2 on the big picture of mouse

- For GHUB: click and select DISABLE from the drop-down menu
- For LGS:  click and select "Unassign" from the drop-down menu